# Unable to start Neo4j on port 80

Tags: neo4j

I am using **CentOS**.

I am unable to start **neo4j** on port 80. Starting on port 7474 works, but for my case, my school only allows me to expose port 80 to the public. I am having trouble starting it: it is stuck at "**waiting for server to be ready............."** and does not finish up.

If I am using **sudo service neo4j-service start**, I get the error message  `"rm: cannot remove '/neo4j-test/data/neo4j-service.pid': No such file or directory".`

Suspecting it could be apache that prevents me from using port 80, I have used yum to uninstall httpd, however, the problem persists.

What could be possible reasons that I am unable to start **neo4j** on port 80?

Comment: Would you show us the content of conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf ??

Comment: I've managed to start neo4j on port 80 for now. I did this by reinstalling the service and setting the user to run neo4j to be root. It seems only root was able to open port 80. So, at least for now, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the last line from the file conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf from

```
wrapper.user=neo4jwrapper.user.created=false
```

to

```
wrapper.user=neo4j
wrapper.user.created=false
```

Comment: My last line of conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf is wrapper.user=neo4j
wrapper.user.created=false

Comment: Changing it didn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try changing the user from "neo4j" to "root" in order to use port 80:

```
wrapper.user=root
wrapper.user.created=false
```

It works for me in Linux.